# Usages of enum and struct instead of switch statement in C#

Tags: c#, struct, enums, switch-statement

I am using below code to perform a conversion depending on the type of user input using switch statement. Is it possible to use "enum" and "struct" instead of switch statement here?

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

namespace Problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double centimeter, liters, kilometer, kilogram;
            WriteLine("Enter the value you wanted to convert: ");
            int input = ToInt32(ReadLine());
            WriteLine("\n Press Any Of The Given Choices \n I->convert from inches to centimeters." +
                      "\n G->convert from gallons to liters.\n M->convert from mile to kilometer."+
                      "\n P->convert from pound to kilogram.");
            char choice = Char.ToLower(ToChar(ReadLine()));
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 'i':
                    centimeter = input / 0.3937;                       //1 cm is equal is 0.3037 inch
                    WriteLine($"In Centimeters: {centimeter}");
                    break;
                case 'g':
                    liters= input * 3.78;                             // 1 gallon=3.78 litters
                    WriteLine($"In Liters: { liters}");
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    kilometer = input *1.60;                          // 1 mile=1.4 KM
                    WriteLine($"In kilometer: { kilometer}");
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    kilogram = input * 0.453;                          // 
                    WriteLine($"In kilogram: { kilogram}");
                    break;
                default:
                    WriteLine("You Enter A Invalid Choice, Please Enter A Valid Choice...!");
                    ReadLine();
                    break;
                   }
            ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary` instead of `switch` statement.
For more cleaner way you can create interface

```
public interface IConverter
{
    string GetFormattedResult(int value);
}
```

Then create own implementation for every unit you have

```
public class CentimeterConverter : IConverter
{
    private const double COEFFICENT = 0.3937;
    public string GetFormattedResult(int value)
    {
        var centimeter = input / COEFFICENT ;
        return $"In Centimeters: {centimeter}";
    }
}
```

Then in your code create Dictionary with Key - choice char and Value - instance of Converter implementation

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var converters = new Dictionary<char, IConverter>
    {
        { 'i', new CentimeterConverter() },
        { 'g', new LitersConverter() }
    }

    WriteLine("Enter the value you wanted to convert: ");
    int input = ToInt32(ReadLine());

    var choiceText = 
        "Press Any Of The Given Choices
         I->convert from inches to centimeters.
         G->convert from gallons to liters.
         M->convert from mile to kilometer.
         P->convert from pound to kilogram.";
    WriteLine(choiceText);

    char choice = Char.ToLower(ToChar(ReadLine()));

    var converter = converters[choice];
    WriteLine(converter.Convert(input));

    ReadKey();
}
```

For making keys little bid more readable you can use static class with constants

```
public static class ConverterKayes
{
    public const char InchesToCentimaters = 'i';
    public const char GallonsToLiters = 'g';
}
```

Enums are integer type, so you can create enum where names will keys

```
public enum Keys
{
    I = 1,
    G = 2
}
```

But this enum gives no more value to readability of your code.

If you really want enums then you can use `DescriptionAttribute` where you can define keys in the attribute

```
public enum Keys
{
    [Description("I")] InchesToCentimeters = 1,
    [Description("G")] GallonsToLiters = 2
}
```

But the you will need create some method to retrieve value from that attribute.
Same for coefficents - it is much easy save them as constants of the static class.

Another approach can be `KeyedCollection`, it can be suitable for your case, because you have same logic for all keys, only values changes

```
public class ConverterToContinentalUnit
{
    public char Key { get; set; }
    public double Coefficent { get; set; }
    public string PrefixForResult { get; set; }

    public string GetFormattedResult(int value)
    {
        var continentalUnit = input / Coefficent;
        return $"{PrefixForResult}: {continentalUnit}";
    }
}

public class ConverterCollection: KeyedCollection<int, ConverterToContinentalUnit>
{
    // This need to be implemented and return key value
    protected override int GetKeyForItem(ConverterToContinentalUnit item)
    {
        return item.Key ;
    }
}
```

Then use it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var converters = new ConverterCollection();
    var toCentimeters = new ConverterToContinentalUnit 
    { 
        Key = "i", 
        Coefficent = 0.3937, 
        PrefixForResult = "In Centimeters"
    }

    converters.Add(toCentimeters );

    WriteLine("Enter the value you wanted to convert: ");
    int input = ToInt32(ReadLine());

    var choiceText = 
        "Press Any Of The Given Choices
         I->convert from inches to centimeters.
         G->convert from gallons to liters.
         M->convert from mile to kilometer.
         P->convert from pound to kilogram.";
    WriteLine(choiceText);

    char choice = Char.ToLower(ToChar(ReadLine()));

    var converter = converters[choice];
    WriteLine(converter.Convert(input));

    ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums supports "byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong". It doesn't support double or float. But you can use struct for it.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct MyUnits
        {
            public const double Centimeter = 0.3037;
            public const double Liters = 3.78;
            public const double Kilometer = 1.60;
            public const double Kilogram = 0.453;
        }

        enum MyUnitEnum
        {
            Centimeters,
            Liters,
            Kilometer,
            Kilogram,
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double centimeter, liters, kilometer, kilogram, final = 0;
            string unitWord;
            WriteLine("Enter the value you wanted to convert: ");
            int input = ToInt32(ReadLine());
            WriteLine("\n Press Any Of The Given Choices \n I->convert from inches to centimeters." +
                      "\n G->convert from gallons to liters.\n M->convert from mile to kilometer." +
                      "\n P->convert from pound to kilogram.");

            char choice = Char.ToLower(ToChar(ReadLine()));

            if (choice == 'i')
            {
                final = input / MyUnits.Centimeter;
                unitWord = MyUnitEnum.Centimeters.ToString();
            }
            else if(choice == 'g')
            {
                final = input / MyUnits.Liters;
                unitWord = MyUnitEnum.Liters.ToString();

            }
            else if (choice == 'm')
            {
                final = input / MyUnits.Kilometer;
                unitWord = MyUnitEnum.Kilometer.ToString();
            }
            else if (choice == 'p')
            {
                final = input / MyUnits.Kilogram;
                unitWord = MyUnitEnum.Kilogram.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                unitWord = "You Enter A Invalid Choice, Please Enter A Valid Choice...!";
            }

            WriteLine("In " + unitWord + final);
            ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```